# tableview bounces on updating of cell on button click

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, ios11

[Table bounce on updating of cell label number of lines.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKyK0.gif)

I'm updating my cell label number lines and the table bounces.
My code is as follows.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)        
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! VendorTableViewCell
     tableView.beginUpdates()
    cell.cell_description.numberOfLines = (cell.cell_description.numberOfLines == 0) ? 2 : 0
        self.cellStates?[indexPath.row - 1] = (cell.cell_description.numberOfLines == 0) ? .expanded: .collapsed
    defer { 
           tableView.endUpdates() 
          }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)        
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! VendorTableViewCell 
    self.cellStates?[indexPath.row - 1] = (cell.cell_description.numberOfLines == 0) ? .expanded: .collapsed
    self.tableView.reloadData()

}
```

and put this in cellForRow

```
    cell.cell_description.numberOfLines = (cell.cell_description.numberOfLines == 0) ? 2 : 0
```